# how to add json to backbone,js collection using fetch

Tags: json, backbone.js

I am trying to get backbone.js to load json.
The json loads but i am not sure how to get the items into my collection.
Or maybe that happens automatically and i just can't trace out. scope issue?

//js code

```
//model
var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'nike',
        img: "http://www.rcolepeterson.com/cole.jpg"
    },
});
//collection
var ClientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: Client
    },
    model: Client,
    url: 'json/client.json'
});
//view
var theView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new ClientCollection();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render: function () {
        alert("test" + this.collection.toJSON());
    }
});
var myView = new theView();
```

//json

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "WTBS",
            "img": "no image"
        },

        {
            "name": "XYC",
            "img": "no image"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your json is not in the correct format, you can fix the json or add a hint to backbone in the parse method:

```
var ClientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: Client
    },
    model: Client,
    url: 'json/client.json',

    parse: function(response){
       return response.items;
    }
});
```

Or fix your JSON:

```
 [
        {
            "name": "WTBS",
            "img": "no image"
        },

        {
            "name": "XYC",
            "img": "no image"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work. if i keep the json the same and add parse:function(response, xhr){                    
      alert("Collection: ClientList : parse: " + response.items.length) i get an alert. i tried changing the json and got no alerts in the collection or view
                  return response.items;
      } i see an alert. I get no alert in my render function in my view

Comment: @ColePeterson can you make a jsfiddle

Comment: I was not positive how to set this up is jsfiddle so sorry my example is incomplete. but here it is  at jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cole/bQHsb/) any help would be awesome. again the parse works but the render in the view never fires.

Comment: @ColePeterson it works fine, you had a very old backbone version that didn't even have a "reset" event. http://jsfiddle.net/bQHsb/3/

Comment: yaaaaa!!!!! OMG i thought i was crazy. i don't know why i had such a out of date file. thanks soooooo much. i would have continued forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you use rest api, try turn off these parameters:

Backbone.emulateHTTP
Backbone.emulateJSON